# Upload & Read eBooks in Chrome (i.e. Maintain a Cloud Library)

Tags: ebook-readers, mobi, library

For some reason I haven't been able to find anything - extension, app, website - that let's me take my ebook library to the cloud *and* read from it. There are two solutions I've been able to find, but they don't work quite as well as I want them to.

First, Google Play Books. I can upload books there, I can download them to my devices, sync reading progress, actually read them... but it only works for the EPUB (and PDF, but I don't read PDFs) format. No MOBI.

Alternatively, I've got a Calibre library set up in Google Drive, which is a really wonderful way to be able to access the hundreds of books I've got there, but while Calibre itself can open nearly any format out there, I can only use it on a computer, and only on a computer I can install it and Google Drive on. No browser or mobile app.

I guess what I am asking here is something with everything Play Books has, but also MOBI support. Has anyone seen such a tool?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Kindle Web Reader](https://read.amazon.com/)? Kindle supports MOBI and you can [import personal documents](http://www.theverge.com/2011/12/27/2664121/how-to-transfer-personal-documents-kindle-ios-app) into your Kindle Library via an email address that is attached to your Amazon/Kindle ID.

You can access your Kindle library through a web browser, and if you use Chrome, there is a Chrome App that supports Offline reading. I believe your personal documents will be synched across devices just like native Kindle books.

Comment: This could work. I knew about the Kindle Cloud Reader, but not about the ability to import personal documents. I'll see how well this works and update this.

Comment: If one emails an EPUB file to a kindle account (attached to a Kindle device), won't Amazon convert that to MOBI for the user? It used to do that.

Comment: no @Bulrush you have to convert the `epub` to `mobi` first -- then you can send the `mobi` to your `kindle` e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding, personal documents aren't readable in the cloud app for the Kindle but only the `kindle` e-book reader.

Purchased content can be accessed through the app.

Almost all purchased content can be accessed directly through the `kindle` reader.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess what I am asking here is something with everything Play Books
> has, but also MOBI support. Has anyone seen such a tool?

I am happy to tell you that yes there is such a tool. BookFusion allows you to upload, organize, read and manage your entire collection of eBooks across iOS, Android and Desktop(via Web App). It supports MOBI, EPUB, PDF and other formats.

Your reading progress, highlights, notes and annotations will always be synced across all your devices.  More at https://www.bookfusion.com/reading

There is even a Calibre plugin that makes it easy for you to upload books you have in Caliber. More at https://www.bookfusion.com/reading/calibre

PS: Founder at BookFusion. Please DM or reply with feedback.